# What's the difference between Git add (ctrl+A) and Stage to Commit (ctrl+T) in the git GUI?

Tags: git, github, git-gui, git-add, git-stage

If git add <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> starts tracking changes AND stages changes to already tracked files, why should I ever use Stage to Commit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in the git gui ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer to my question:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in the GIT GUI is actually to ADD A NEW REMOTE and is not the same as GIT ADD !
In the GIT GUI, there does not seem to be any distinction between 'adding' and 'staging' , both are done by the 'stage to Commit' command: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. And according to this: http://hoth.entp.com/2008/11/5/what-git-add-really-means  ,
'git stage' is an alias for 'git add'

Thanks aardvarkk for your answer. I suppose 'adding' can be considered the 'first staging' of a file, but really 'adding' means 'adding to the stage' or 'staging to commit'.

**Concisely,**
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> = 'stage to commit' in the GIT GUI = 'git add' at the command line 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> = add a new remote

Comment: The same is "adding to [commit] index" and "indexing".

Answer (score 1):

Stage to Commit would be for a file that already has changes being tracked which you've since altered. You would generally only "add" a file once to begin tracking changes, and thereafter you would simply stage the file for commit that you've changed.

Comment: But "add" , ie CTRL+A , also stages changes to tracked files, so CTRL+T seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

According to [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stage), they are synonyms. The command prepares the files for commit.

Example: `git add app_controller.php`