# how to force git to commit a symlink (as a symlink at git repository) that was a renamed regular file?

Tags: git, symlink

I had a regular file named `ScriptA.sh` and renamed it to `ScriptB.sh`.

I created a symlink `ScriptA.sh` pointing to `ScriptB.sh`.

When I commit/push it and go check at the remote repository, there has `ScriptA.sh` and `ScriptB.sh` with the full script content... I was expecting `ScriptA.sh` to have only the path to `ScriptB.sh` as its data...

Worse is: if I change the data at `ScriptB.sh`, only it is detected as having changed, therefore I can only commit that one... and cannot commit `ScriptA.sh`!

I thought if I changed the symlink contentet of `ScriptA.sh` to be `../bin/ScriptB.sh`, commit and then change it back, and commit again, it may fix? or may I mess something? EDIT: I just tested and the symlink change was not detected...

EDIT: I tried to remove the symlink `ScriptA.sh` and commit, and add it back and commit again, but the uploaded file had not the symlink data but the regular file full data :(

PS.: I use Ubuntu/Nautilus with RabbitVCS Git.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git gui` (it is the normal `git` command with a `gui` parameter).
Its detection for symlinks was flawless!
You may need to install the package *git-gui*.

You have to click on *Stage to Commit* after selecting the files, then *Commit* and finally *Push*; and you will have to type the remote repository password on the terminal from where you run `git gui`, when asked.

Obs.: just a tip to make it have the same diff compare found at RabbitVCS. At "Add New Tool Command" on tools menu, put this simple command: meld $FILENAME

Ref.:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux
[What's the difference between Git add (ctrl+A) and Stage to Commit (ctrl+T) in the git GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929691/whats-the-difference-between-git-add-ctrla-and-stage-to-commit-ctrlt-in-t)